# select only records that does not appear for a long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database which consists of two columns:

```
CardNumber           RecordDate

1`                   2015-03-01
2                    2015-04-01
3                    2015-04-02
4                    2015-03-18
2                    2015-03-19
3                    2015-03-18
1                    2015-03-01
4                    2015-04-02
2                    2015-03-30
2                    2015-03-01
1                    2015-03-01
```

I want to select only the `CardNumbers` having `RecordDate` before a certain date (eg: `2015-03-15`). So, if a `cardNumber` was recorded on `2015-03-22` and `2015-03-01` it should not be selected. Although, if a card was last recorded, for instance, on `2015-03-01` it should be selected.

Comment: So, what is the question then? This should be really simple. Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This will get card numbers with last record date < '2015-03-15'

```
select cardnumber
from tbl
group by cardnumber
having max(recorddate) < '2015-03-15'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HAVING` clause with a `MAX` aggregation

```
SELECT CardNumber
FROM   SomeTable
GROUP BY CardNumber
HAVING MAX(RecordDate) < '2015-03-15'
```

Comment: I expect you will need a group by to do aggregation.

Comment: True.  MySQL got me lazy on that one, as it does not require the `GROUP BY` to work.